# Adding a sprite to fixture in box2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I'm trying to add a sprite texture to a box2d fixture in cocos2d.
Currently I have a dynamic body (textured with a sprite) and the fixture I'm trying to add the texture to is being added to the body.

Here's my code:

```
b2PolygonShape fixtureShape;
fixtureShape.SetAsBox(0.6f,0.9f,b2Vec2(-1 + 0.1, 1), 45);
b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
fixtureDef.shape = &fixtureShape;
fixtureDef.density = 0.1f;


b2BodyDef bodyDef;
bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
b2Body *body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

b2CircleShape dynamicBox;
b2FixtureDef mainFixtureDef;
mainFixtureDef.shape = &dynamicBox; 
mainFixtureDef.density = 0.1f;

body->CreateFixture(&mainFixtureDef);
body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);

CCPhysicsSprite *sprite = [CCPhysicsSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"sprite1.png"];

[parent addChild:sprite];

[sprite setPTMRatio:PTM_RATIO];
[sprite setB2Body:body];

[sprite setPosition: ccp( p.x, p.y)];
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation on adding sprites to fixtures, does anyone know if it's possible?

Comment: No. Fixtures are used by the physics engine only. Sprites hook onto Body's in box2d.
This explains a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5862128/2700842

Comment: @NickTerry: Sprites are not related to the bodies. The are two different engines. Box2d - for physics, Cocos2d - for graphics. It is fully up to you how you draw the physics. You are not limited to `hooking sprites onto Body`

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. But you have to do it yourself. Fixtures are shapes (with props) attached to the `b2body`. It looks pretty the same as adding children to `CCNode`.

So you can create a root node (just a grouping `CCNode`) and synchronise its position/rotation with the `b2Body` transformation. When adding fixtures to the body - add sprite for that fixture to the root node. And position it the same way you positioned the fixture.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by setting sprite as a user data of fixture. And setposition of sprite according to the fixture position in the world